Make show-parens-mode recognize changed syntax table
I'm using a lot of bra-ket-like notation in LaTeX-mode, meaning things like ⟨f|, so I put
(modify-syntax-entry ?\⟨ "(|" LaTeX-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\⟩ ")|" LaTeX-mode-syntax-table)

into the .el file corresponding to my default LaTeX-package. This makes commands like forward-sexp go from an open ⟨-bracket to a |-sign if one is closer than the next ⟩-bracket, but ⟩ also matches ⟨ if it is closer because this match is in a syntax table that is used to generate the LaTeX-mode-syntax-table, and I like it that way because I also occasionally use statements ⟨f⟩ in my TeX-files. But show-paren-mode still only matches ⟨ with a ⟩-bracket when I have point on it, and similarly, rainbow-delimiters-mode only color-matches ⟨-brackets with ⟩-brackets, though that's not in core Emacs. I tried finding out how to make show-paren-mode recognize ⟨-|-matches, but I'm a bit out of my depth here. Does anyone know why show-paren-mode doesn't recognize ⟨-| pairs even though they are in the LaTeX-mode-syntax-table? Is it because the ⟨⟩-match is later on in the table, and if so, what is the correct way to get show-paren-mode to match ⟨ with | while keeping the match of ⟨ with ⟩ in the LaTeX-mode-syntax-table?
